# Gitpod with C++ and Raylib

Tags: c++, raylib, gitpod

I like to use [Gitpod](https://www.gitpod.io/) and use for almost all of my projects.

I start learning [Raylib](https://www.raylib.com/) and would like to use Gitpod to in those projects.

I already tried using this template (VS Code based): https://gitlab.com/GameDevTV/CPPCourse/raylib-vscode-template, but I didn't have great success

Is there any way to use C++ and Raylib with Gitpod? If yes how? Are there any templates? :)

(Sorry if this question is kinda of obvious)

Answer (score 1):

There was a similar question at the Gitpod Discord server:
https://discord.com/channels/816244985187008514/1002193641344872518

(You might need to open the link again after joining the server)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't have a good answer. 

Comment: True, it doesn't provide you a concrete solution. But it does provide some hints. If you like, feel free to send a message in that thread, I might pick it up someday when I have time.